# I have a problem and also nothing I type here works?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have an error when compiling and running a PyQt5 app. I believe it is a dependency issue.
The error is as follows,

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.
```

Comment: Does this happen with *any* PyQt app (for example: `app = QApplication(); test = QWidget(); test.show(); app.exec_()` )? If not, provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: execute `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 python your_script.py`